# Unbind an event-delegated, multi-argument event listener with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have a question that has been touched upon by different answers but as far as I can find not in the same details as I require. I wish to unbind an event listener, but with a couple of restraints.

1. Event delegation to child items
2. The event listener takes a secondary argument
3. The event function must unbind itself inside an if-clause

I dumbed it down to the example below. When you click the first button, you can then click any of the other buttons. The text of the first button will change accordingly. However, because the event listener is never removed you can keep changing your "choice" and click on any of the other buttons. What I want is that when you click on the first button, you can only click on one other button after which the listener is removed. In practice that means that if you want to change your "choice" you first need to click the first button again, after which the event listener is re-attached.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button")
const div = document.querySelector("div")

function listen(text, evt) {
  if (evt.target.tagName == "BUTTON") {
    btn.textContent = text + evt.target.textContent
    // Unbind listen function from div so that that `btn` must be clicked every time
    // you want to change the selected button.
    // The following does NOT work.
    div.removeEventListener("click", this)
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  div.addEventListener("click", listen.bind(this, "I selected "))
})
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>

<div>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, I tried removing the event listener but since I used `bind` (to get the secondary argument working), I don't think `this` is the same reference anymore. How can I get this to work without relying on other libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` would have never worked anyway. It normally refers to DOM element the handler is bound to, not the function itself.

You could go about this in different ways. One possibility is to introduce a helper for binding event handlers, which in turn will pass a "remove" function to the handler.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button")
const div = document.querySelector("div")

function addEventListener(element, type, handler, ...args) {
  const handlerWrapper = function(event) {
    return handler.call(this, event, remove);
  };
  const remove = () => element.removeEventListener(type, handlerWrapper);

  element.addEventListener(type, handlerWrapper, ...args);
}


function listen(text, evt, remove) {
  if (evt.target.tagName == "BUTTON") {
    btn.textContent = text + evt.target.textContent
    // Unbind listen function from div so that that `btn` must be clicked every time
    // you want to change the selected button.
    remove();
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  addEventListener(div, "click", listen.bind(this, "I selected "))
})
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>

<div>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

---

Having said that, if you always want to execute an event handler at most *once*, pass the [`once: true` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters) when binding the event handler.

Comment: I tried implementing your first suggestion into the code snippet in the OP, but it does not work - the behaviour is the same as before, i.e. the "other" buttons can be clicked indefinitely and the listener never seems to be removed. The second option does not seem to apply here due to event delegation: the listener should only be removed when a button is clicked, not when the div is clicked per se.

Comment: My mistake, I was removing the wrong function. I fixed the code and made it a runnable example.